# Include mySQL DB value in PHP email form body

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am using PHP to email data that is entered via a HTML contact form using the code below:

HTML

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>" method="post" name="form" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" title="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `item_id`='" . $id . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $item_id = $fetch['item_id'];
        $item_name = $fetch['item_name'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $to = "testemail@testemail.com";
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $item_name = $_REQUEST['item_name'];
        $subject = "New Message";
        $body = "Name: $name \n\n Email Address: $email \n\n Item Name: $item_name \n\n";
        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $body);
        echo 'Sent';
        die;
    }
?>
```

The email is sent correctly and contains the values entered in the 'Name' and 'Email' input form fields, but the $item_name variable is blank? The only way I can get it to work is to echo out the $item_name variable into a hidden input field and then include that in the email $body. Is there an easier way?

```
<input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $item_name; ?>"/>
```

EDIT:

I have removed:

```
 $item_name = $_REQUEST['item_name'];
```

within the if statement but the $item_name variable still displays nothing when the email is sent via PHP?

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7, use `mysqli_*` functions or PDO instead

Comment: Try to use var_dump($item_name) if there is data return

Comment: var_dump($item_name) displays the correct value

Comment: good note on deprecation - but author didnt mention if they were on php 7 yet

Answer (score 0):

Close - you're staring too directly at it. Notice you're asking for the REQUEST param rather than your fetched param - try this :

I initially suggested this, without seeing the forest for the trees(it clears up a redundant and error (XSS INJECTION!) issue but still fails :

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `item_id`='" . $id . "'";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  //these variables only exist in this scope
  $item_id = $fetch['item_id'];
  $item_name = $fetch['item_name'];
  //assuming you've found what you're looking for, terminate the loop, conditionally
  if ($item_id != null && $item_name != null)
  {
    break;
  }

}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $to="testemail@testemail.com";
  $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
  $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
  //$item_name=$_REQUEST['item_name']; 
  $subject="New Message";
  $body="Name: $name \n\n Email Address: $email \n\n Item Name: $item_name \n\n";
  $sent=mail($to, $subject, $body);
  echo 'Sent'; die; 
}
```

instead, the primary reason for your issues are scoping, try to do this:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `item_id`='" . $id . "'";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
// placeholder variables in the scope you are interested in!
$item_id = null;
$item_name = null;
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // now these reference a different (parent) scope
  $item_id = $fetch['item_id'];
  $item_name = $fetch['item_name'];
  //assuming you've found what you're looking for, terminate the loop, conditionally
  if ($item_id != null && $item_name != null)
  {
    break;
  }

}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $to="testemail@testemail.com";
  $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
  $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
  //$item_name=$_REQUEST['item_name']; 
  $subject="New Message";
  $body="Name: $name \n\n Email Address: $email \n\n Item Name: $item_name \n\n";
  $sent=mail($to, $subject, $body);
  echo 'Sent'; die; 
}
```

basically what was happening is the `$item_[id|name]` only existed within your while loop. when you asked for them elsewhere and they were available? I dont have an answer for that because thats not available to us in this question spec.

TL:DR ~ your `$item_[id|name]` variables where scoped to within EACH iteration of the while loop, **for this example**

establish a higher level variable, and it will be referenced and the value set.

also - You were originally re-writing the `$item_name` variable in your if statement

EDIT #3billion : the documentation is a little dry(as in : stereo installation instruction) but as someone that has been developing with over 20 different languages for 15 years --- **learn to love unit tests**

phpunit is a pretty decent suite. theres a manual and theres a learning curve, but it will make you a better programmer (if thats your goal - i absolutely do not wish to sound condescending - lots of time people are 'programming' to fill a specific requirement and save their company money - no harm no foul! )

unit tests make me better everyday.

https://phpunit.de/

Comment: I have removed the $item_name=$_REQUEST['item_name']; but the $item_name variable inside the email $body still doesn't display on the sent email? If I echo $item_name elsewhere on the page, the correct value from DB displays?

Comment: ahhh so i dont know your DB data - but what could be happening is you're getting and then overwriting the variables in your while loop. You should terminate your loop once the values have been set - i updated my example ~ otherwise you run the risk of iterating /past/ the variables and resetting them to null

Comment: i used `return` instead of `break` - too many languages these days. use `break` - updated example with this

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but it doesn't solve the problem. I have echoed the variable at various places throughout the page and they display fine, but within the $body they do not? I assume because I am not using echo $item_name?

Comment: well - really the way you are assigning `$body` "should work fine" (i say 'fine' because its gruesome but functional and should work nps) and i don't see any issue with your text interpolation.HA oh man i need coffee - refer to updated example

Comment: note the comments ive left in both code blocks as well - PHP lets you do "some crazy stuff" but the scoping is pretty good (compared to JS hoisting, but thats another story)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `$item_name=$_REQUEST['item_name'];` inside the isset function then you will get the actual $item_name from the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `$item_name` declarations in your code:

```
$item_name = $fetch['item_name'];
```

AND

```
$item_name = $_REQUEST['item_name'];
```

So, the 2nd one will overwrite the first one. Thus, if there isn't a `<input>` for `$_REQUEST['item_name']`, it will be blank.

To solve this problem, remove the 2nd declaration, so that `$item_name` will hold the value fetched from the database.

---

**Note:**

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7, use `mysqli_*` functions or PDO instead.

Comment: @MikeE Does any of these answers help you? Accept the best one, thanks :)